# Printing a binary tree

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I just started working with classes in Python and I am at a roadblock trying to print a binary tree that I created. Here is the code I have:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number=number
        self.right=None
        self.lef=None

    def add_node(self,number):
        if number < self.number:
            self.left = self.left.add_node(number)
        if number > self.number:
            self.right = self.right.add_node(number)
```

The first part represents the root of the tree and the add_node function adds a node in the tree. I created a new instance for the root of the tree:

> Tree = Node(6)

The problem that I am facing is printing the tree. If I just say `print Tree`, I get this:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x10f6e5210>
```

Somebody told me that I have to create a function to actually print the tree and this function looks like the function that's creating a new node but so far I wasn't able to do that. Any help please?!

Comment: The clue that it looks like the `add_node()` method was probably referring to the fact that it would also be recursive -- e.g. printing the tree would consist of printing the left and right sub-trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `__str__` method to determine how your node object reacts when used as a string, i.e. `str(Node(6))` . This is useful if you want to give out a string representations in print statements etc. without calling methods directly.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number=number
        self.right=None
        self.lef=None

    def add_node(self,number):
        if number < self.number:
            self.left = self.left.add_node(number)
        if number > self.number:
            self.right = self.right.add_node(number)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

print Node(6)
```

**Edit:**

While `__str__()` returns bytes, `__unicode__()` returns characters. `__unicode__()` is actually supposed to replace `__str__()` , so it's actually recommended to use `__unicode__()` instead (in Python 2.x there's both for compatibility reasons).

A 3rd way to represent your object is `__repr__()` which is used for less formal string representations but rather for debugging etc. The returned string should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value.

For more information have a look at the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: I've upvoted your answer but you should also say about `__unicode__` and `__repr__` in my opinion.

Comment: Figured it couldn't hurt to do so. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add a function to create a function to `print` the value at the node. The function can be as simple as

```
def dis(self):
    print(self.number)
```

And you can now print using

```
print (Tree.disp())
```